# Replacing div html() by echoing PHP - how to?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a multiple product elements that get their class and ID from PHP:

```
$product1["codename"] = "product-1";
$product1["short"] = "Great Product 1";

$product2["codename"] = "product-2";
$product2["short"] = "Great Product 2";



<div class="leftMenuProductButton" id="'. $product1["codename"].'" >'. $product1["short"].'</div>

<div class="leftMenuProductButton" id="'. $product2["codename"].'" >'. $product2["short"].'</div>
```

These display as:

```
<div class="leftMenuProductButton" id="product-1" > Great Product 1</div>

<div class="leftMenuProductButton" id="product-2" > Great Product 2</div>
```

In the page, I have an element that I want to replace the HTML:

```
        <div id="productPopupTop">
         //Replace this content
        </div>
```

Using jquery, I have tried the following:

```
$( '.leftMenuProductButton' ).hover (
            function () {

                var swapNAME = $(this).attr("id"); //gets the ID, #product-1, #product-2 etc. This works.
                $("#productPopupTop").html('  <? echo $' + swapNAME + '["short"] ?>'); //This is supposed to get something like <? echo $product-1["short"] ?> This doesn't appear to work.


            },
            function () {
            //this is just here for later

    });
```

If I try to do an `alert('<? echo $' + swapNAME + '["short"] ?>');` it will literally display something like `<? echo $product-1["short"] ?>`

Please note that both the Javascript and the PHP are externally linked in a PHP file (index.php <<< (js.js, products.php)

**QUESTION:** How do I replace the HTML() of `#productPopupTop` with the `["short"]` of a product? If I should use Ajax, how would I code this?

Comment: you can't use php and javascript together that way. php is evaluated on the server, javascript on the client

Comment: ok kind of makes sense... but if I can't do it this way, then *how* should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$( '.leftMenuProductButton' ).hover (
            function () {
                $("#productPopupTop").html($(this).html());


            },
            function () {
            //this is just here for later

    });
```

Comment: That's Funny... way too simple!

Answer (score 1):

As knittl mentioned, php is a pre-processor on the server, and can't do anything once the page has been sent to the client.

The options I can think of are

1. Store the product information in javascript on the client (i.e. a javascript array that is populated with php)
2. Use ajax to query the server with a codename and receive the corresponding data (i.e. `server.com/getshort.php?codename=product-2`, which would respond with `Great Product 2`).

If the text within the tag is always the same, @[Kasia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471219/replacing-div-html-by-echoing-php-how-to/2471288#2471288)'s answer will work, and is simpler.